# Apply regular expression in dataframe to extract values into new columns

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a text file and imported it into a dataframe like this, I am thinking to develop an regular expression to extract different values into new columns. How can I achieve it or any other solution can produce the same output?

```
Full text
NEW ACCOUNT       ABC COMPANY  00123

                  CCY/BALANCE  USD 3,600

ACCOUNT APPROVAL  ABC COMPANY  00123

NEW ACCOUNT       BBC COMPANY  00124

                  CCY/BALANCE  USD 5,600
```

Expected output:

```
TRAN DESCRIPTION CUSTOMER NAME  A/C NO. CCY BALANCE
NEW ACCOUNT      ABC COMPANY    00123   USD 3,600.00
ACCOUNT APPROVAL ABC COMPANY    00123        
NEW ACCOUNT      BBC COMPANY    00124   USD 5,600.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """\
NEW ACCOUNT       ABC COMPANY  00123

                  CCY/BALANCE  USD 3,600

ACCOUNT APPROVAL  ABC COMPANY  00123

NEW ACCOUNT       BBC COMPANY  00124

                  CCY/BALANCE  USD 5,600
"""

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(s), header=None)
df.columns = ["TRAN DESCRIPTION", "CUSTOMER NAME", "A/C NO."]
df["CCY BALANCE"] = df.loc[df["TRAN DESCRIPTION"].isna(), "A/C NO."]
df["CCY BALANCE"] = df["CCY BALANCE"].bfill(limit=1)
df = df[df["TRAN DESCRIPTION"].notna()]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   TRAN DESCRIPTION CUSTOMER NAME A/C NO. CCY BALANCE
0       NEW ACCOUNT   ABC COMPANY   00123   USD 3,600
2  ACCOUNT APPROVAL   ABC COMPANY   00123         NaN
3       NEW ACCOUNT   BBC COMPANY   00124   USD 5,600
```